# ng include not inputting HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

Here's a Plunker with the problem in question: https://plnkr.co/edit/3I3DbYle9urs9UwugfpA?p=preview

I've made a very simple example that shows what isn't working. I use ngInclude as follows:

```
<div ng-include="'header.html'" ng-controller="TestController"></div>
```

It seems pretty straightforward. I've searched other questions and answers about this topic and now know that I should use single quotes inside double quotes, that I need to be running this on a server (I am), and so on. But no matter what I try, it isn't working.

I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Several mistakes: 1. You're using `ngAnimate` but forgot to include the source 2. Mismatched module names (`govExp` vs. `plunker`, the latter which is used in the HTML) 3. Missing controller definition for `MainCtrl` 4. Incorrect controller definition for `TestController`. See https://plnkr.co/edit/XOEfWGQFtalPHrjAqDDO?p=preview

Comment: Got it. Rather new to this and not very good yet. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the controller method a function.

Your code

```
 angular.module('govExp').controller('TestController', []);
```

Corrected code

```
angular.module('govExp').controller('TestController', [function(){
    //do stuff
]);
```